# Per-screen font config?

Tags: multi-monitor, fontconfig

Is there a way to have different fontconfig settings per screen ?

I have two 1080p monitors, however one is 13" and the other 27". I would like antialiased fonts on the small monitor, and non-antialiased fonts on the big monitor.

Comment: Interesting question. I can imagine this would be useful for different subpixel rendering too, e.g. if one is RGB and the other is BGR.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`xrdb` uses the C preprocessor (because of course it does), so it supports conditions.  Here's a snippet from my `.Xresources`:

```
#if SCREEN_NUM == 0
Xft.dpi: 157
#endif

#if SCREEN_NUM == 1
Xft.dpi:  96
Xft.antialias: 0
#endif
```

Now `xrdb -merge` will do the right thing on each monitor, and when you log in, assuming one of the myriad X initialization scripts bothers to look at your `.Xresources`, it will also be set correctly.

(Note: the [Arch Linux Font Configuration](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/font_configuration) page has more examples, but in the interest of preserving this for posterity, I have included the relevant example above.)

Comment: wow, that's great ! finally a way !

Comment: looks like Xft.dpi is case sensitive, only Xft.dpi works for me

Comment: @vvolkov is right.  I have fixed the explanation above.

Comment: "because of course it does" :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do it:

1. Set the config for the secondary monitor in `.Xresources` and run `xrdb`
2. Start the program and place it on your secondary monitor
3. Change the values back in `.Xresources` and run `xrdb`

Here's an example script for starting intellij Idea on secondary tilted monitor:

```
#!/bin/sh
sed -i 's/.*Xft.rgba:\s*rgb.*/Xft.rgba: vrgb/' /home/babken/.Xresources
xrdb /home/babken/.Xresources
intellij-idea-ultimate-edition &
sed -i 's/.*Xft.rgba:\s*vrgb.*/Xft.rgba: rgb/' /home/babken/.Xresources
xrdb /home/babken/.Xresources
```

Though this will work if you keep that program on that monitor only (like I do).

Comment: As above, you don't need to run `xrdb` more than once, since it is multi-display aware.